# ObjectAnimator: how to detect framerate?

Tags: android, objectanimator

I use ObjectAnimator and testing app on different devices.  On some old slowly phones it animates too bad (no GPU, no memory etc), so I want to automatically switch user to second (lite) version of an app.

So how to detect what ObjectAnimator is slowly?

1. Is it have some framerate report? I found nothing.
2. Is Choreographer have same listener? it lists errors in catlog, but I want to get it in code.

   **01-22 05:55:15.775: INFO/Choreographer(3794): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.**

Note: I know how to parse catlog via system command, but it seems to me it is not a smart  or fast solution.

Note2: I do not need to make things faster. I need to detect slow phone.

Comment: The message says you are doing too much work on the main thread, so the animations stutter. Just move the work to a background thread and the animations will run smoothly.

Comment: will not of course. So, how to catch Choreographer's message?

Comment: Yeah...well...ok. Good luck.

Comment: ElDuderino, I have to do stresstest on a slow device. There is no any "main thread work", only ObjAnimator. 

Or, imagine, user run some services, updates, background processes. My app needs to detect slow speed of itself and correct it.

So I need framerate, or catch log. (below I post some solution)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this solution works fine

It can be called from ObjAnimator's loop (listener - onRepeat, for example)

You can count events and make conclusion about speed of device.

p.s. it is not smart enought, but until nobody answered about native framerate report...

```
boolean getCatLog(){
    boolean yes=false;
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String output;
        String lastLine = null;
        while ((output = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lastLine = output;
        }
        if(lastLine!=null && lastLine.contains("Choreographer")){
            Log.d(TAG,"yes!");  //do not remove!
            yes=true;
        }
        reader.close();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return yes;
}
```